# Is there a way to get the average of a COUNT DISTINCT aggregate in Tableau?

Tags: count, distinct, average, tableau-api, trend

I have a data set that is batch data and connected to Tableau (9.2 Version), therefore, the ticket count is applied as a COUNTD measure in every sheet..  The issue I am having now is I want to get a weekly average (for the previous 31 weeks).  Quite unsure of how to approach this.  When I change the Measure Value to AVERAGE, it neglects the COUNTD filter.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `window_avg(countd(measure))`

Comment: Window_avg of count gives the same results as count.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an LOD to do this.

```
{FIXED WEEK([date field]) : AVERAGE(COUNTD([measure]))}
```

This is some more [information](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) on Tableau's site about LOD's.

Comment: Average isn't a Tableau function, AVG is.  Error: "Is already an aggregation and cannot be aggregated further".

Answer (score 0):

It's an average.  Take the Sum or CountD of the value and divide it by the CountD of week[date].